# How to read from a .sh file in anaconda/command prompt (windows)?

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda

In Linux we use 
bash filename.sh for reading commands from the shell script. What is the alternative in windows?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative in Windows is .cmd or .bat files.
[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/) you can find an example on how to write a simple script and execute it.

Also you can use [PowerShell scripts](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-your-first-powershell-script-file-windows-10) .ps1. It is somewhat more difficult, but is more powerful.